# PostgreSQL Function : Error operator doesn't exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a function which let to delete rows where `date_information`column is inferior than `now() - interval '2 months'`.

I get this issue when I try to update a row :

```
sql> UPDATE "public"."token_jwt_usertoken" SET "date_information" = '2020/02/08' WHERE "id" = 1
[2019-02-08 09:27:56] [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying < timestamp with time zone
[2019-02-08 09:27:56] Indice : No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
[2019-02-08 09:27:56] Où : PL/pgSQL function after_update_token() line 3 at IF
```

This is my function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION after_update_token() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $after_update_token$
  BEGIN
    IF to_timestamp(old.date_information, 'YYYY/MM/DD') < now() - INTERVAL '2 months'
      THEN
        DELETE FROM token_jwt_usertoken WHERE to_timestamp(old.date_information, 'YYYY/MM/DD') < now() - INTERVAL '2 months';
    END IF;
END;
```

My table looks like this :

```
id  token  user_id  period_duration  date_information

2   eyJ0    318 1y  2018/02/07
```

How I can rewrite my function correctly where I'm using `old.date_information` field ?

Thank you

**EDIT :**

I edited the type of `date_information` to set it to `date` type.

The code becomes :

```
CREATE FUNCTION after_update_token() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $after_update_token$
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM token_jwt_usertoken WHERE old.date_information < now() - INTERVAL '2 months';
    RETURN NULL;
  END;

$after_update_token$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER after_update_token AFTER UPDATE ON token_jwt_usertoken FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE after_update_token();
```

And it returns this issue :

> [2019-02-08 10:06:41] [2F005] ERROR: control reached end of trigger
>   procedure without RETURN [2019-02-08 10:06:41] Où : PL/pgSQL function
>   after_update_token()

This is the DDL :

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.6.11
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 11.1 (Ubuntu 11.1-1.pgdg18.04+1)

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: token_jwt_usertoken; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: ocabr_user
--

CREATE TABLE public.token_jwt_usertoken (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    token character varying(256) NOT NULL,
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    period_duration character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    date_information date
);


ALTER TABLE public.token_jwt_usertoken OWNER TO ocabr_user;

--
-- Name: token_jwt_usertoken_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: ocabr_user
--

CREATE SEQUENCE public.token_jwt_usertoken_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE public.token_jwt_usertoken_id_seq OWNER TO ocabr_user;

--
-- Name: token_jwt_usertoken_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: ocabr_user
--

ALTER SEQUENCE public.token_jwt_usertoken_id_seq OWNED BY public.token_jwt_usertoken.id;


--
-- Name: token_jwt_usertoken id; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: ocabr_user
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.token_jwt_usertoken ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('public.token_jwt_usertoken_id_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Data for Name: token_jwt_usertoken; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: ocabr_user
--

--
-- Name: token_jwt_usertoken_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE SET; Schema: public; Owner: ocabr_user
--

SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.token_jwt_usertoken_id_seq', 6, true);


--
-- Name: token_jwt_usertoken token_jwt_usertoken_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: ocabr_user
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.token_jwt_usertoken
    ADD CONSTRAINT token_jwt_usertoken_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- Name: token_jwt_usertoken token_jwt_usertoken_user_id_0de4884e_uniq; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: ocabr_user
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.token_jwt_usertoken
    ADD CONSTRAINT token_jwt_usertoken_user_id_0de4884e_uniq UNIQUE (user_id);


--
-- Name: token_jwt_usertoken token_jwt_usertoken_user_id_0de4884e_fk_auth_user_id; Type: FK CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: ocabr_user
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.token_jwt_usertoken
    ADD CONSTRAINT token_jwt_usertoken_user_id_0de4884e_fk_auth_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES public.auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

And the update command executed is :

```
UPDATE "public"."token_jwt_usertoken" SET "date_information" = '2021-02-07' WHERE "id" = 3;
```

Comment: What data type is `date_information`?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `IF` statement is completely useless as that is the same condition as in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This is odd. Can we get the output of `\d public.token_jwt_usertoken` in `psql`? Also, what do you get for `\df to_timestamp`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The type of`date_information` is a varchar(50) .. It's not fault, I'm improving code from an other developer .. To my mind, it should be a date type .. Ok I can remove the `IF` statement so.

Comment: Can you post the DDL for the table and the update statement that is causing this error?  Everything looks to me like it should work.

Comment: @Hambone yes ! Just one question, what means DDL ? It's maybe an english acronym that I don't know in English but in French ;)

Comment: It means "le poission rouge."  Just kidding.  DDL is the table definition (DDL = Data Definition Language)

Comment: @Hambone I'm editing my question with information

Comment: Wow, I copied all of this and did not get any errors on either insert or update.  What version of PosgreSQL are you on?  When did the error occur, when you were defining the trigger or when you did the insert/update?